# How to lessen CSS

Tags: css

```
<div id="tt">test1</div>
    <div id="blabla">test2</div>
<div id="test">
    <div id="blabla">test3</div>
    <div id="tt">test4</div>
</div>
<style>
    #tt {color:blue;}
    #blabla {color:green;}
    #test #tt, #test #blabla etc... {color:red;}
</style>
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating #test?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Is your example right? Duplicate id's and a reference to #t which isn't in your html. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You should probably use a class.

Comment: Hmm could you be more specific please? :) It's interesting

Comment: You should be more specific. Your code is invalid in it's current state. as nc3b suggests, you should be using a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do. If you want all the text nodes to be red and the parent element is `#test`, then you just need  `#test {color:red}`. If you need to be more specific, and give a color only for a child, then you can use `.child {color:blue}`, but if you want to color a child of `#test`, then you will need to specify the ancestor descendant, in other words `#test .child {color:green}`

---

**Edit**

Example according my comment http://jsbin.com/udoya3

Comment: I want to lessen code and avoid conflicts with # names of the rest css files. I have listed conflict situation in the example. If you will remove each #test in the styles, it will overlap the previous set of css rules

Comment: You avoid "conflicts" if you don't apply multiple times rules with with the same properties. In your example there is not reason to write `#test #tt, #test #blabla etc... {color:red;}`, you just need `#test * {color:red}` and will be red the `tt` and `blabla`. Also keep in mind that in your HTML document you can use only time time an `id`, if you want to use it multiple times (such as `tt` & `blabla` you need the `class` attribute). Check the link my post.

Comment: And if there is somewhere another <div class="test"> about which you don't know and can't change it? :)

Comment: OK i got the idea to use id once and then class after it.

Answer (score 2):

For the particular example that was the question before it underwent major revisions:

```
* { color: red }
```

CSS is very much about context though. It isn't very good when dealing with hypotheticals that have little resemblance to the real code.

Comment: :D it will select all. I was talking about selecting variant.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using id here, you should use id and class. An id should be unique : one id, one element. Class aren't unique. A class can have more than one element.

```
<style>
    .tt,.t {color:red;}
</style>

<div class="tt">test1</div>
<div id="test">
    <div class="tt">test2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't get the idea mate :) i know how to use css and that id should be uniq by standart

Answer (score 0):

`#test, #t, #tt { color:red; }`

is perfectly valid code.

an `#id` takes precedence over any other styling (ie a class) which can have adverse effects, but may also be desired.

what are you actually trying to do? save a few characters when writing your css?